# Angular 4 cdk table trackby does not work. The whole table is rerendered

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

Solved:
The problem was in rxJS threads. One thread too frequently passed empty array, so it reseted the table.

The table is updated every 4 seconds. To stop blinking I apply a trackBy function. I see that the function is triggered, but the whole table is rerendered. I guess I do something wrong.
What I do...
Set the tracking function.

```js
<mat-table ... [trackBy]="trackById">
```

Implement the tracking function.

```js
 trackById(index, item) {
    console.log(item._id);
    return item._id;
  }
```

The table is updated by the table's Data Source update.

```js
 updateOperations() {
    this.dataSource = new Source(this.forexService);
  }
```

The whole component is here https://gist.github.com/vlikin/6f130c53b1fd38116afe20d15a2afc40 .

This component displays a list of operations. It retrieves data from two observables. The data source of the table is created once. The data change is initated by Behaviour Subject dataS. Data retring process is locate in the function `update`. mat-table component uses the directive trackBy that have to optimize the output. But it still blinking.

There are two plunks with and without trackId:
With - https://embed.plnkr.co/wK5Jh4tIgY9p9Gw4rfhx/
Without - https://embed.plnkr.co/Rc9z9aXlalQe8yWpGjUq/

There are not such effects at all. At my application it is blinking.

I hope, anybody will help me. Regards.

Comment: Just    return item //or index and *ngFor ".....; trackBy: trackById". If you are not using ngFor then post more code

Comment: The whole component is here https://gist.github.com/vlikin/6f130c53b1fd38116afe20d15a2afc40 .

This component displays a list of operations. It retrieves data from two observables. The data source of the table is created once. The data change is initated by Behaviour Subject dataS. Data retring process is locate in the function `update`. mat-table component uses the directive trackBy that have to optimize the output. But it still blinking.

Comment: Mat-table doesn't have trackby attribute, as far as know( at least I could've find anything related), plus if in the example (which is with) if you set console.log in trackById method, it's never fired, which makes reinforce my thought that it's not an attribute

Comment: Exists https://material.angular.io/guide/cdk-table#connecting-the-table-to-a-data-source

Comment: It's cdk-table and not mat-table, right?

Comment: mat-table adds only styles. It was a single library, later it was separated to reuse without material design styles.

Comment: trackBy option might not be reimplanted in mat-table, as It's not fired

Answer (score 0):

It was a logic issue. DataSource was combined from few streams. So one of the stream reseted the data.

Comment: hello viktor, i am having the same issue with my mat tree. could you please elaborate on the issue ? I am currently updateing the datasource using an asynch httpclient get request.

Comment: I need to look at code. In my case it did not work because after data array the empty array passed, that reseted the tracking feature. So trackId was unuseful there but it worked.

Comment: i did some tests and it appears i have to keep modifying the original list values instead of overriding the old ones. ex: `myBehaviorSubject.next(ReturnWithModifications(myBehaviorSubject.getValue()))` and not `myBehaviorSubject.next(httpRequestWithNewValuesAndOldValues())`

Comment: so if i understand this correctely. this only works if i EDIT the exisiting value in the observable?